# Creating build of a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt

I have a stand alone project in my eclipse.There are few external jar as well.The programme is executing well and giving required result. Now i need it to run from command prompt.and i just want to run the class file generated by eclipse. how i will be able to run it.When i am tring to run it from commend prompt it is giving class not found exception.I also tried to make an executable jar,but that is also not running.do i need to create executable jar or i can simply run it from command prompt..tell me the way out..

thanks
koushik

Comment: this is one good reason why not to use IDEs, and use Gmake. you always know exactly what files are created and how they run.

Comment: Thanks harry.But can u please tell me how exactly i will run it from comnd prmpt..i mean where i will put those external jar etc...

Comment: Can you give more details on "*but that is also not running*"?

Answer (score 2):

A step by step guide [at](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html)

I recommend you to go through jar, class path and other basic building blocks of java for eg [check this about jar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html)

Answer (score 0):

try using this command `java -cp . package.name.className`